# Randomly offset duplicate points along linestring X meters using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, linestring, linear-referencing, offset

The query below selects all duplicate points on a line, which overlay one another, then randomly assigns each point location within a certain radius.  The last step assigns each point back on what I hope is the same line -- the nearest line.  This isn't the best solution, though.

I really want to randomly space these points along the length of the linestring they are on.  I have looked around for a potential solution but just can't seem to find one.

```
dup_pts AS (                    -- Select duplicate points to distribute along line
    SELECT * FROM midpoint_join AS a, midpoint_join AS b
    WHERE ST_Equals(a.st_lineinterpolatepoint, b.st_lineinterpolatepoint) 
    AND a.id <> b.id
), dup_info AS (                 -- Assign point information to duplicate points
SELECT d.id AS id, d.lic_li_no AS lic, desc,
           random() * 360.0 AS ang,
           random() * 0.00001 AS rad, -- radius
           geom
    FROM   dup_pts d
), rand_pts AS (                 -- randomly assign points to radius
    SELECT id, lic, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(
         ST_X(geom) + rad*SIND(ang),
         ST_Y(geom) + rad*COSD(ang)
       ), 4326) as pt_geom FROM  dup_info)
, point_line AS (                 -- send random points back to nearest line segment
    SELECT * FROM rand_pts;
    CREATE TABLE point_line AS              
    SELECT pt.id, ST_ClosestPoint(a.geom, pt.geom) geom
    FROM rand_pts pt
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT p.geom 
  FROM public.linestring p
  ORDER BY p.geom <-> pt.geom
  LIMIT 1) a;
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Your question title seems to be the opposite of the solution you are looking for. Needless to say that is rather confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update duplicates with a randomly interpolated point on the nearest line, e.g.:

```
UPDATE
  <points> AS pt
SET
  geom = (
    SELECT
      ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
        ln.geom,
        -- interpolate point at random fraction of line length
        random()
      )
    -- find nearest line to point ((K)NN query)
    FROM
      <lines> AS ln
    ORDER BY
      ln.geom <-> pt.geom
    LIMIT
      1
  )
-- update only those points with duplicates
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      <points> AS _pt
    WHERE
      -- bbox of a point is the point; alternative to ST_Equals for points
      _pt.geom && pt.geom
      AND
      -- update all duplicates but the one with the lowest <id>
      _pt.<id> < pt.<id>
  )
;
```

Comment: ERROR:  function st_lineinterpolatepoint(geometry, geometry, double precision) does not exist
LINE 64:       ST_LineInterpolatePoint(

Comment: I think the problem is with ST_LineInterpolatePoint:  It can only accept a line geom not a line and point geom.  I changed it and it seems to work.

Comment: @MJM oh yes, how dumb. Glad you found out yourself.

Comment: @MJM consider accepting an answer if it completely adresses and solves your question.

Answer (score 9):

Group by geometry to find the duplicates, join the line to the points, [interpolate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html) the duplicates at a random distance along the line, union with the non duplicates:

```
--Find the duplicates by grouping by geometry
with dups as (
select array_agg(p.id) ids, p.geom, count(*)
from test.pointsonline p
group by p.geom
having count(*)>1
)

--Interpolate the duplicates along line at a random fraction of the line length
select unnest(ids) id, st_lineinterpolatepoint(st_linemerge(l.geom), random()) as geom
from dups d
join test.lineswithpoints l
on st_dwithin(d.geom, l.geom, 5) --join the lines 5 m within

union
--Union with the points that are not duplicates
select id, geom
from test.pointsonline
where id not in(select unnest(ids) from dups)
```

[image]